# How to check if two strings are almost equal with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a quiz app made with Ionic and Angular 4. User have to submit answer, I check if it's the same as the good answer or not.
I would like to check string correspondence, and handle event according to the correspondence between good answer and user answer.

In Exemple :
If the answer is 'azerty', and he wrote 'mzerty', I would like to allow him to continue.
If user wrote 'qwerty', or something too different, he failes.

Comment: You're looking for Levenstein distance.

Comment: [Levenstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: One method would be a regex. Something similar to /[qwerty]+/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple demo with Levenstein distance would be like that:

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import levenshtein from 'fast-levenshtein';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  score$: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
    this.initScore();
  }

  private initForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      str1: '',
      str2: '',
    });
  }

  private initScore() {
    this.score$ = this.form
      .valueChanges
      .pipe(
        map(({str1, str2}) => levenshtein.get(str1, str2))
      );
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="str1">

  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="text" formControlName="str2">
</form>

<br>

<div>
  Levenshtein score: {{ score$ | async }} 
</div>
```

**Stackblitz live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usydyu**

Comment: (ofc based on the score you could do just what you want, I'm only displaying it here)

Comment: Thanks to this example, I was able to easily adapt it to what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a method which will return you how many characters are matched. so on basis of matched characters and the length of string you can decide weather its a good answer or not.

```
function checkEq(str1, str2){
        var arr1 = str1.split('');
        var arr2 = str2.split('');
        var counter = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
            if(arr1[i]==arr2[i]){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: What result would that give if you compare `something` and `_something`?